# Erlang: What happens when you f() a Pid in erl?

Tags: concurrency, process, erlang, pid, erl

Say I'm working with some simple processes in `erl`:

```
1> Fun = fun(F) -> F(F) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.82930912>
2> Pid = spawn(fun() -> Fun(Fun) end).
<0.178.0>
3> f(Pid).
```

What happens when I do `f(Pid).`? Does the process exit or do I just lose my reference to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html) `f(Pid)` removes the binding of variable Pid, the process is not stopped.

You can test it in this way: suppose you have a gen_server called `myserver` which is based on the skeleton provided by emacs erlang mode.

```
1> {ok, Pid} = myserver:start_link().
{ok,<0.39.0>}
2> f(Pid).
ok
3> gen_server:call(pid(0,39,0), mycall).
ok
4> gen_server:call(myserver, mycall).
ok
```

As you can see even though we did `f(Pid)` we can still contact the process using its pid or the atom used during registration (in our case the module name).

Comment: Thanks! I feel that the documentation was vague regarding what happens when you remove the binding, but your example makes it explicitly clear.

Comment: @agarrett Processes never go away just because there are no references to them. They either die when they have completed their function, an error occurs or they are killed by another process.